# How to calculate the Month to Date(MTD) and Year to Date(YTD) in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate the `MTD` and `YTD` for the given dataframe.I have two columns named `bp` and `actuals`.

`MTD` and `YTD` values for `bp` is the cumulative average.But the `MTD` and `YTD` values for `actuals` is the cumulative average without taking the zero values.

For example, if actuals value for 2023-04-01 is 10, then its corresponding `mtd_actuals` column value will be 10.actuals value for 2023-04-02 is 20, then its corresponding `mtd_actuals` column value will be 15. actuals value for 2023-04-03 is 0, then its corresponding `mtd_actuals` column value will be 15.

Input dataframe :

```
data = {
'date': ['2023-04-01', '2023-04-02', '2023-04-03', '2023-04-04', '2023-04-05'],
'category': ['QUALITY PARAMETERS', 'QUALITY PARAMETERS', 'QUALITY PARAMETERS', 'QUALITY PARAMETERS', 'QUALITY PARAMETERS'],
'parameter': ['TBR', 'TBR', 'TBR', 'TBR', 'TBR'],
'region': ['DELHI', 'DELHI', 'DELHI', 'DELHI', 'DELHI'],
'factory': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC'],
'actuals': [10, 20, 0, 0, 10]
```

}

output dataframe:

```
date            category        parameter ...   actuals mtd_bp mtd_actuals ytd_bp ytd_actuals
2023-04-01  QUALITY PARAMETERS       TBR  ...      10     51   10.000000   51   10.000000 
2023-04-02  QUALITY PARAMETERS       TBR  ...      20     51   15.000000   51   15.000000
2023-04-03  QUALITY PARAMETERS       TBR  ...       0     51   15.000000   51   15.000000
2023-04-04  QUALITY PARAMETERS       TBR  ...       0     51   15.000000   51   15.000000
2023-04-05  QUALITY PARAMETERS       TBR  ...      10     51   13.333330   51   13.333330
```

I have used below code for calculating the mtd_actuals and ytd_actuals:

```
df['mtd_bp'] = df.groupby([df.date.dt.to_period('m'), 'category', 'parameter', 'region', 'factory']).actuals.expanding().mean().droplevel([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

df['mtd_actuals'] = df.groupby([df.date.dt.to_period('m'), 'category', 'parameter', 'region', 'factory']).actuals.expanding().mean().droplevel([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

df['ytd_bp'] = df.groupby([df.date.dt.to_period('A-MAR'), 'category', 'parameter', 'region', 'factory']).actuals.expanding().mean().droplevel([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

df['ytd_actuals'] = df.groupby([df.date.dt.to_period('A-MAR'), 'category', 'parameter', 'region', 'factory']).actuals.expanding().mean().droplevel([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Here `mtd_bp` and `ytd_bp` values comes correctly.But `mtd_actuals` and `ytd_actuals` are not correct.

Can anyone suggest a solution or modify the `mtd_actuals` and `ytd_actuals` code to get the correct output?

Comment: I think it would be better to give a minimal example by removing unnecessary columns and rows. The rows are too long. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: can you suggest a solution to get the required output@ 
Panda Kim

Comment: If you create a minimal example and explain your logic exactly, someone will help you. (including me)

Comment: @PandaKim I cut the input down to the relevant part for OP's question

Comment: I suggest you read the post I linked to and take a look at the examples other people have created in question.

Answer (score 1):

Your example was not ideal for showing the expansion by month, excluding 0, so I created a new one.

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'date': ['2023-04-01', '2023-04-02', '2023-04-03', '2023-04-04', '2023-04-05', '2023-05-01', '2023-05-02', '2023-05-03'], 
         'bp': [51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51], 'actuals': [10, 20, 0, 0, 10, 20, 10, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

`df`

```
    date        bp  actuals
0   2023-04-01  51  10
1   2023-04-02  51  20
2   2023-04-03  51  0
3   2023-04-04  51  0
4   2023-04-05  51  10
5   2023-05-01  51  20
6   2023-05-02  51  10
7   2023-05-03  51  0
```

**Step1**

make period grouper for groupby

```
grouper = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.to_period(freq='M')
```

`grouper`

```
0    2023-04
1    2023-04
2    2023-04
3    2023-04
4    2023-04
5    2023-05
6    2023-05
7    2023-05
Name: date, dtype: period[M]
```

**Step2**

mask & groupby by grouper & expanding

```
df['actuals'].mask(df['actuals'].eq(0)).groupby(grouper).expanding().mean().droplevel(0)
```

output:

```
0    10.000000
1    15.000000
2    15.000000
3    15.000000
4    13.333333
5    20.000000
6    15.000000
7    15.000000
```

Let's compare df and output.

```
         df                         output
    date        bp  actuals
0   2023-04-01  51  10              10.000000
1   2023-04-02  51  20              15.000000
2   2023-04-03  51  0               15.000000
3   2023-04-04  51  0               15.000000
4   2023-04-05  51  10              13.333333

5   2023-05-01  51  20              20.000000
6   2023-05-02  51  10              15.000000
7   2023-05-03  51  0               15.000000
```

I want you to create the columns you want as output.

Comment: `MTD` values of `actuals` are shown in `mtd_actuals` column and `YTD` values of `actuals` are shown in `ytd_actuals` column.Need to group on the basis of 'category', 'parameter', 'region', 'factory';because multiple values will be there under these columns.Can you show the code for `mtd_actuals` and `ytd_actuals` seperately.@Panda Kim

Comment: I think you can do this by applying the groupby method to the code above.
I believe that the value of a question is that you can get code from a minimal example and then solve your problem based on that code. I do not believe that the value of a question is to provide a complex example and then copy and paste the code that can be applied directly. @AbinBenny

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
'date': ['2023-04-01', '2023-04-02', '2023-04-03', '2023-04-04', '2023-04-05'],
'category': ['QUALITY PARAMETERS', 'QUALITY PARAMETERS', 'QUALITY PARAMETERS', 'QUALITY PARAMETERS', 'QUALITY PARAMETERS'],
'parameter': ['TBR', 'TBR', 'TBR', 'TBR', 'TBR'],
'region': ['DELHI', 'DELHI', 'DELHI', 'DELHI', 'DELHI'],
'factory': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC'],
'actuals': [10, 20, 0, 0, 10]}

# Convert data into DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['actuals'].replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)

# Compute the cumulative average and fill NaN values with the previous value
df['ytd'] = df['actuals'].expanding().mean().ffill()


print(df)

date            category parameter region factory  actuals        ytd
0  2023-04-01  QUALITY PARAMETERS       TBR  DELHI     ABC     10.0  10.000000
1  2023-04-02  QUALITY PARAMETERS       TBR  DELHI     ABC     20.0  15.000000
2  2023-04-03  QUALITY PARAMETERS       TBR  DELHI     ABC      NaN  15.000000
3  2023-04-04  QUALITY PARAMETERS       TBR  DELHI     ABC      NaN  15.000000
4  2023-04-05  QUALITY PARAMETERS       TBR  DELHI     ABC     10.0  13.333333
```